# Puppet : resource already defined error

Tags: puppet, rhel6

I am trying to create multiple directories and then copy files to each of the directories . For that I have created the following resource

```
$dirs=myapp

$appdirs = [  "/data/tomcat/$dirs/conf", "/data/tomcat/$dirs/config" ]


 file { $appdirs:
 ensure => "directory",
 owner => "root",
 group => "root",
}

file { "Copy Directory":
path => "/data/tomcat/$dirs/conf",
ensure => "present",
recurse => "true",
source => "puppet:///modules/tomcat8/conf/"
 }
}
```

But I am getting the error already defined as shown below

```
 Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: 
 Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias File[Copy Directory] to
 ["/data/tomcat/jacplus8/conf"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/app.pp:20; 
 resource ["File", "/data/tomcat/jacplus8/conf"] already declared at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production
 /manifests/classes/app.pp:14 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/app.pp:20:1
 on node Node-003.example.com
```

I need to copy files using the second resource file { "Copy Directory":} to the destination directory after it is created using the first resource file { $appdirs:} but it is giving me already defined error although the resource names are different . I am looking for workarounds so that I can create the directories and then copy files in it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it like this by rewriting my manifests rules . For creating the directories , I remove the arrays and created each of the directory by using a single file resource .Also removed the path variable from filename and the directory to be created was provided as a resource name.

```
   class app {
$dirsname=myapp

file { 'directory':
     path => "/data/tomcat/${dirsname}/",
     ensure => "directory",
     owner => "root",
     group => "root",
}

file { '/data/tomcat/${dirsname}/conf':
    ensure => "directory",
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    require => File['directory'],
   }

file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config':
    ensure => "directory",
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    require => File['directory'],
  }

file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/':
path => "/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/",
ensure => "present",
recurse => "true",
source => "puppet:///modules/conf/"
```

}

```
file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config/':
path => "/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config/",
ensure => "present",
recurse => "true",
source => "puppet:///modules/config/"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like this:

```
  $dirs = [
    "/app/logs",
    "/app/logs/archive",
    "/app/logs/archive/${instance_name}" 
  ]
```

with an error like

*resource ["File", "/app/logs/archive"] already declared*

Turns out, `$instance_name` was empty, so it was indeed, trying to declare `/app/logs/archive` twice.

Answer (score 0):

As info for those  still landing here (search engines show me this result as 1st).

If some resource is already declared (for example in a module) and it conflicts with a declaration in a node or a class that is managed by you, one way to avoid the conflict is.

```
if !Resource['title'] {
  #then you manage the resource
}
```

example

```
if !Package['centos-release-scl'] {
    # this is already declared (by the zabbix module)
    package { 'centos-release-scl':
        ensure => installed,
    }
}
```