# Puppet File resource :"Parent Directory does not exist" error

Tags: puppet, rhel6

I am getting the following error during directory creation using file resource

```
Error: Cannot create /data/tomcat/${dirsname}/conf; parent directory /data/tomcat/${dirsname} does not exist
Error: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/${dirsname}/conf]/ensure: change from absent to directory failed: Cannot create /data/tomcat/${dirsname}/conf; parent directory /data/tomcat/${dirsname} does not exist`

Error: Cannot create /data/tomcat/$dirsname/config; parent directory /data/tomcat/$dirsname does not exist
Error: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config]/ensure: change from absent to directory failed: Cannot create /data/tomcat/$dirsname/config; parent directory /data/tomcat/$dirsname does not exist`
```

But technically the directories are getting created as can can be seen from the `puppet` command output

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/jacplus8/conf/context.xml]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}ba798c2de6dd554035c05352891a0d07'
Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/jacplus8/conf/server.xml]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}6298e53557ead6855cef9bcbb082a074'`

Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config/]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/jacplus8/config/runtime.settings]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}2e2596f0f9107c8cfc783da3d5004dae'`
```

I checked the directory structure , the directories are available but not sure why it is showing the error messages. My manifests rule are as follows

```
class app {
$dirsname=myapp8

file { 'directory':
     path => "/data/tomcat/${dirsname}/",
     ensure => "directory",
     owner => "root",
     group => "root",
    }

 file { '/data/tomcat/${dirsname}/conf':
    ensure => "directory",
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    require => File['directory'],
  }

 file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config':
    ensure => "directory",
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    require => File['directory'],
   } 

  file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/':
    path => "/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/",
    ensure => "present",
    recurse => "true",
    source => "puppet:///modules/conf/"
   }

  file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config/':
    path => "/data/tomcat/$dirsname/config/",
    ensure => "present",
    recurse => "true",
    source => "puppet:///modules/config/"
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> file { '/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf':
> ```

Replace the single quotes with double quotes, then the variable will be interpolated. Do this on all lines with single quotes and variables (there are four).

As you can see from the log, it's creating directories with the variable name in it, not the directory with the variable replaced:

> ```
> Notice: /Stage[main]/App/File[/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/]/ensure: created
> ```

Comment: If I reply single quotes with double quotes , it gives me "Already defined error" like below: Failed to apply catalog: Cannot alias File[/data/tomcat/$dirsname/conf/] to ["/data/tomcat/myapp/conf"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/app.pp:66; resource ["File", "/data/tomcat/myapp/conf"] already declared at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/app.pp:20

Comment: Also for the manifests as in original description, I can see that the directories are physically created on the system . Only issue was the error message

Comment: That's a different problem then, which you already filed at https://serverfault.com/questions/844830. You shouldn't manage the same directory multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. After creating the  directory , I am pushing files to that directory using two different file resources